# Light2D not rendering in build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been working on a project that uses the universal render pipeline and the new Light2D for some scenes. I load the lights in via scripts on awake. For some reason, everything looks fine in the editor but when I make builds of the game, none of the lighting effects display and the project looks just like it did before I switched to the URP. I'm using Unity 2019.4.10f1.
Any ideas on if there is a setting I need to enable for the lights to work with the build or if this is a Unity bug or just not supported yet?

Thanks!